# Random real numbers with uniform distribution in verilog

Tags: random, verilog, distribution, uniform

Is there a function to generate random real numbers in the range [0,1] with uniform distribution in verilog. I tried `$random%2` but it generates only integer values {-1,0,1}. There is a function `uniform()` in VHDL, is there a similar function in verilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

The $random function returns a random 32-bit integer number. With some simple math you can convert that to a real number and map that in the range -1..1. (The modulo operator is not the right way to do it) But you will not have 'infinite' random numbers in that range as there are only 2^32 different numbers which $random can return.

I am not sure, but I don't think there is any programming language which supports infinite floating random numbers between -1 and 1. As far as I know they all use an pseudo random generator which generates an integer, You then have to manipulate it to get the random probability curve you want.